# SlideUp goes up although selected class has not been left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
function hoverimgon(elem){
             $(elem).find('.credentials-popup').slideDown(800);
    }
               
    function hoverimgoff(elem){
            $(elem).find('.credentials-popup').slideUp(800);
    }
```

```css
.credentials-element {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}


.ct-el-color {
  height: 250px; 
  background-color: coral;
}

.credentials-popup{
  display: none;
  max-width: 1170px;
  background-color: #DD3330;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="credentials-element" onmouseover="hoverimgon(this)" onmouseout="hoverimgoff(this)">
            <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
          
            <div class="credentials-popup">
                Something
            </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="credentials-element" onmouseover="hoverimgon(this)" onmouseout="hoverimgoff(this)">
            <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
          
            <div class="credentials-popup">
                Something
            </div>
      </div>
```

SlideUp goes up although selected class has not been left. Although several elements have the same class, the second div should only appear with the mouseover element and not with all. If the second is selected with the mouse, this should not disappear, just as it is the case, you should have the possibility to select something in the credentials-popup. What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery `:visible` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and have it hide when the mouse leaves the hidden message area.

```js
function hoverimgon(elem) {
  var $slide = $(elem).find('.credentials-popup');
  if (!$slide.is(":visible")) { // only slide down if hidden
    $slide.slideDown(800)
  }
}

function hoverimgoff(elem) {
  if ($(elem).is(":visible")) { // only slide up if visible
    $(elem).slideUp(800);
  }
}
```

```css
.credentials-element {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.ct-el-color {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: coral;
}

.credentials-popup {
  display: none;
  max-width: 1170px;
  background-color: #DD3330;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="credentials-element" onmouseover="hoverimgon(this)">
  <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
  <div class="credentials-popup" onmouseout="hoverimgoff(this)">
    Something
  </div>
</div>

<div class="credentials-element" onmouseover="hoverimgon(this)">
  <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
  <div class="credentials-popup" onmouseout="hoverimgoff(this)">
    Something
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

you are should use a proper jQuery call, and since you are using jQuery, there is no need to write JavaScript functions for such a simple job. I have made the solution for you in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c8dh5qbk/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="credentials-element">
  <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
  <div class="credentials-popup">Something</div>
</div>
<div class="credentials-element">
  <div class="ct-el-color"></div>
  <div class="credentials-popup">Something else</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.credentials-element').mouseover(function() {
    if (!$(this).children('.credentials-popup').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).children('.credentials-popup').slideDown(800);
    }
  }).mouseout(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.credentials-popup').is(":visible")) {
        $(this).children('.credentials-popup').slideUp(800);
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.credentials-element {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.ct-el-color {
  height: 50px; 
  background-color: coral;
}
.credentials-popup{
  display: none;
  max-width: 1170px;
  background-color: #DD3330;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 50px;
  padding:10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix his issue. The mouseout should be attached to the `.credentials-popup` element.